How to crop part of an image in SDL2
I'm working on a raycasting engine in C using the SDL2 library. I figured out how to render sprites by loading in images like this:
void draw_sprite(SDL_instance map , SDL_instance display, ray *rays)
{
    float scale;
    int i, j;
    SDL_Rect draw = {0, 0, 0, 0}, mappoint = {15 * 16, 5 * 16, 16, 16};
    sprite test = {0, {15 * 16 + 8, 5 * 16 + 8}, -1};
    coordsf temp = {test.pos.x - posX, test.pos.y - posY};
    coordsf result = {(temp.y * cos(theta)) - (temp.x * sin(theta)), (temp.x * cos(theta)) + (temp.y * sin(theta))};
    SDL_Surface *skull = SDL_LoadBMP("skull007.bmp");
    SDL_Texture *image = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(display.renderer, skull);

    scale = 360 / result.y;
    test.pos.x = result.x, test.pos.y = result.y;
    /* Calculate sprite screen positions */
    draw.x = (result.x * 1260 / result.y) + (1260 / 2) - (16 * scale);
    draw.y = (test.z * 1260 / result.y) + (720 / 2);
    draw.w = draw.h = scale * 32;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(map.renderer, 255, 240, 0, 0);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(display.renderer, 255, 255, 255, 0);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(map.renderer, &mappoint);
    SDL_RenderCopy(display.renderer, image, NULL, &draw);
    SDL_RenderDrawRect(display.renderer, &draw);
}

The problem is, sometimes the sprites can be behind walls and I need to be able to crop them to only draw the parts that are visible. How can I accomplish that?
I haven't found many resources about this, but I have seen multiple people suggest the SDL_BlitSurface() function. I have no idea what this does or how to use it though.

you can crop texture when rendering by passing an  SDL_Rect  to the third parameter of SDL_RenderCopy()
